# Earth Exploded, Orbiting and double moons

Tags: planets, moons, orbital-mechanics

I have a scenario which I am too poorly knowledgeable to address, I'm hoping for some expert input.

I'm currently writing a novel, in which a large section of Russia/EU continents were blown up in a fusion/nuclear explosion or perhaps meteor impact (it's less relevant to the post-apocalyptical plot besides radiation).

So now the Earth has been spun off access, with a large chunk blown off the side (think like a bitten apple). The earth was cast in a outward trajectory away from the Earth, with permanent sunshine on America for 213 years whilst still allowing vegetation/evolved human life. The Earth has now rotated away from the sun allowing it to set in the East for those in America.

The debris from the explosion/impact most notably formed 2 large moons. When there was still sunshine for the 213 years - The 1st caused a 3 1/2 hour eclipse, followed by a window of light for 40 mins, with the second causing a 5 hour eclipse. These near replicated the day/night cycle at least for human life, but I imagine would wreck havoc on the weather. Now the sun is too far East to be seen for however long, there will only be moonlight when the two moons are in orbit.

How scientifically, if remotely possible, could any of this theoretically happen. I should say that following the event I only need the Earth to be stable and supportive of life for around 250 years (the moons can join, crash into earth, etc after that hah).

I know I love a good theoretical challenge in my own field, so any inquisitive minds like mine I'd love any and all input, be it astronomy or meteorology. Thanks for taking the time to read, I posted after seeing a great response to a 3 hour eclipse.

Pensive

Comment: Any event which results in *"a large chunk blown off the side"* (not to mention form two moons) will by necessity melt the crust (and boil off the oceans). Any other consequences are irrelevant -- there will be nobody left to experience them.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  @AlexP is right.  This is well beyond an extinction-level event.  Anything big enough to set the Earth rotating backwards would probably pulverize it (you need to hit the planet with 2x the energy of rotation... that's a lot).  But, hours after impact, no life (and probably never again).

Comment: Hi Pensive, Welcome to world building. Think of the Earth as a blob of molten iron covered by a skin about the (proportional) thickness of an orange peel. If you blast a chunk of skin into orbit, the internal molten iron, under pressure, floods out as the Earth settles again into a sphere, and a new crust forms.If you add in enough energy to stop or reverse its spin, you'll have a very large cloud of iron vapor that will coalesce back into a new planet in something close to the orbit that used to be Earth's in a few million years.

Answer (score 6):

There is no theoretical challenge there.

The piece of rock that did in them dinosaurs gave us an impact orders of magnitude more powerful than a lot of nukes combined. It didn't create a new moon, and yet, it sent 90% of all species extinct. If you are creating new moons, you are one upping that event.

Also: throwing rocks up into space will not create new moons instantly. The Moon with a capital M took millions of years to settle from debris, according to the most current model. And the impact that created that debris melted the crust of the Earth, restarting the Hadean.

On top of that, the impact that generated the Moon was against a fairly large body, and its remains may have been the seed around which the Moon coalesced. If you just blow stuff up on the ground, then the most likely scenario is that any piece of rock that does not get accelerated to escape velocity falls back on Earth, even if the fall back takes days. When that debris falls back onto the Earth, the only reason it won't kill anybody is because there won't be anything alive.

Nothing and no one will survive a blast as you propose. That is too absurd even for Silver Age DC comics standards.

Comment: Heavens to Murgatroyd! Nothing was too absurd for Silver Age DC comics! It's still one of the Great Comic Book Eras. The Gospel According to St Mort Weisinger, no less.